# MySQL replication: temporarily prevent specific SQL statements replicating to the slaves?

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to connect and execute one (or sometimes several) SQL statements, and NOT have those replicated to the slaves.

I have no replicate-do or replicate-ignore configs, so I can't `use` some non-replicated database to send the commands from.  And I know about:

```
set global sql_slave_skip_counter = 1
```

But that's on the slave.  I'd like to be able to run a similar command on the master and have the following N commands not sent out to the slaves (which I guess means not logged in the binlogs, either).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`SET sql_log_bin=0` is what you're looking for. Requires SUPER priv., and will turn off logging of commands from your session until you set it back to 1. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-session-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_bin

```
SET sql_log_bin=0;
UPDATE ... ;
INSERT ... ;
DELETE ... ;
SET sql_log_bin=1 ;
```

Comment: The above link is old and dead. At the end of the line for 5.x you probably want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html

Answer (score 2):

BE CAREFUL.....!

`SET sql_log_bin=0;`

Master MySQL server automatically set this 0 value to 1 after a while(after about one minute). It does not wait until we explicitly set it to 1. So according to my experience this not a safe way to turn off binary logging at all.....!

Comment: What if it runs in a transaction?

Comment: System variables do not magically change value when left alone. Your  code is doing this explicitly, it's just you haven't debugged it to determine where and why.